# How to calculate differences scores with R?

Tags: r

So I have 2 sets of data, each comparing a specific category, like so:

```
Category : Solution 1 : Solution 2
1: 5 : 6
2: 7 : 6
3: 4 : 4
4: 8 : 9
```

How do I calculate the difference scores using R specifically? Somehow I need to load the data them calculate `solution1 - solution2` I believe.

Comment: What is df1 exactly? Where did it come from?

Comment: `df1` is the object name of the dataset after the data was read.  I posted that as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could 'read' the dataset using `read.table/read.csv` with the appropriate delimiter.  Based on the example showed, it is `:`.  After the 'data.frame' object is created ('df1'), we can use `transform` or `within` to create the 'Diff' column (i.e. the difference of the "Solution" columns

```
 df1 <- read.table('file.txt', sep=':', strip.white=TRUE, header=TRUE)
 transform(df1, Diff= Solution.1-Solution.2)
 #   Category Solution.1 Solution.2 Diff
 #1        1          5          6   -1
 #2        2          7          6    1
 #3        3          4          4    0
 #4        4          8          9   -1
```

Or

```
 df1$Diff <- with(df1, Solution.1-Solution.2)
```